# javascript - map with conditionally altered nested field

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, if-statement, nested

Given an array such as:

```js
people = [
    {
        name: 'Bob',
        sex: 'male',
        address:{
          street: 'Elm Street',
          zip: '12893'
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Susan',
        sex: 'female',
        address:{
          street: 'Hickory Street',
          zip: '00000'
        }
    }
]
```

I am trying to write a function which will alter specific instances of '00000' in the nested field 'zip' to the string '12893' and return a new array identical to the initial array except **with** the corrected values. My attempt at a function so far is:

```js
function zipFix (initialArray) {
    return initialArray.map(function(person) {
        if(person.address.zip === '00000')
          person.address.zip = "12893"
        return person
    });
}
```

I know this function is altering the values in 'initialArray', which isn't supposed to happen. How can I go about writing my function so that I can effectively use the map function to create a new, corrected array? Thanks.

Comment: You need to return value from callback function too,

Comment: @CodeManiac You're right, I forgot to paste that in.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `map`-ing over the values, you will need to create a copy of each object. The easiest way to do so is with the [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`{...obj}`).

This will "spread" all the values (`name`, `adress`, etc) into a new object. So any changes won't mutate it. However, it's "shallow" meaning *it* will be a new object but its *values* are the same. So since `address` is also an object we need to copy that as well, hence the reason for the nested spread of the `address` value as well.

```js
people = [{
    name: 'Bob',
    sex: 'male',
    address: {
      street: 'Elm Street',
      zip: '12893'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Susan',
    sex: 'female',
    address: {
      street: 'Hickory Street',
      zip: '00000'
    }
  }
]

function zipFix(initialArray) {
  return initialArray.map(function(person) {
    // Create a new "copy" of the person. Using object spread
    // will create a "shallow" copy, so since address is also an
    // object it will have to be spread (same for other objects that might
    // be mutated).
    const newValue = { ...person, address: { ...person.address }}

    if (newValue.address.zip === '00000') {
      newValue.address.zip = "12893";
    }

    return newValue
  });
}

console.log(zipFix(people))
console.log(people) // unchanged
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return values from callback function too, also make a copy of element before assigning to avoid mutability

```js
const people = [{name: 'Bob',sex: 'male',address:{street: 'Elm Street',zip: '12893'}},{name: 'Susan',sex: 'female',address:{street: 'Hickory Street',zip: '00000'}}]

function zipFix (initialArray) {
    return initialArray.map(function(person) {
      let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person))
        if(newObj.address.zip === '00000')
           newObj.address.zip ="12893"
      return newObj
    });
}

console.log(zipFix(people))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
people = [{
    name: 'Bob',
    sex: 'male',
    address: {
      street: 'Elm Street',
      zip: '12893'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Susan',
    sex: 'female',
    address: {
      street: 'Hickory Street',
      zip: '00000'
    }
  }
]

function zipFix (initialArray) {
  return (initialArray.map(({address, ...p}) => (
    address.zip !== '00000' ? { ...p, address } : {
      ...p,
      address: {
        ...address,
        zip: '12893'
      }
    }
  )));
}

console.log(zipFix(people));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const people = [{name: 'Bob',sex: 'male',address: {street: 'Elm Street',zip: '12893'}},{name: 'Susan',sex: 'female',address: {street: 'Hickory Street',zip: '00000'}}]
const zipFix = people.map(({address, ...p}) => ({
  ...p,
  address: {
    ...address,
    zip: address.zip === '00000' ? '12893' : address.zip
  }
}))

console.log(zipFix)
```